# Translating a LP from Excel to Python Pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I need to produce 5000 kgs of steel by mixing 7 alloys parts .
I need to reduce the cost, so i need to pick up the best parts.

The result must respect the main steel caracteristics, for example, the carbon level must be between 2% and 3 %, no more, no less .

The Excel linear solver program already exists ,and is originated  from a professional book.

I'm trying to translate it to a PULP code, now .

My problem is : How to create the copper, carbone, and manganèse constraints ? There are 2 arrays, so I don't know how to do.

It is all in percents, and I don't know how to do . My result is actually wrong, I left the bad constraints I've done for information . It seems that I need to divide by 5000 at one moment, but how should I do ?

*Let me try to explain to you what I can not understand :*

I need 5000 kgs of steel to have 0.60 % of copper in it, but my Copper alloy parts contains 90 % and 96% of copper.
Do you see what I mean, and why it is so difficult to describe  my constraints  ?

```
"" "
 Mining and metals

We make steel with raw materials, we want to reduce the cost of producing this steel
to make more money, but still respecting the minimum characteristics of quality steel

"" "

# Minimize the cost of metal alloys.
# Characteristics of the steel to be made

"" "Element      %Minimum %Max   %Real ( it is a var)
    Carbon       2         3     2.26
    Copper       0.4       0.6   0.60
    Manganese    1.2       1.65  1.20

 "" "
# Characteristics, stocks and purchase price of alloys
"" "

Alloy          C%   Cu%   Mn%     Stocks kg Price € / kg
Iron alloy     2.50 0.00  1.30    4000      1.20
Iron alloy     3.00 0.00  0.80    3000      1.50
Iron alloy     0.00 0.30  0.00    6000      0.90
Copper alloy   0.00 90.00 0.00    5000      1.30
Copper alloy   0.00 96.00 4.00    2000      1.45
Aluminum alloy 0.00 0.40  1.20    3000      1.20
Aluminum alloy 0.00 0.60  0.00   2,500      1.00

"" "

# Import the PuLP lib
from pulp import *

# Create the problem variable
prob = LpProblem ("MinimiserLpAlliage", LpMinimize)

# The 7 vars have a zero limit
x1 = LpVariable ("Iron alloy 1", 0)
x2 = LpVariable ("Iron alloy 2", 0)
x3 = LpVariable ("Iron alloy 3", 0)
x4 = LpVariable ("Copper alloy 1", 0)
x5 = LpVariable ("Copper alloy 2", 0)
x6 = LpVariable ("Aluminum alloy 1", 0)
x7 = LpVariable ("Aluminum alloy 2", 0)


# The objective function is to minimize the total cost of the alloys in EUROS for a given quantity in KGS
prob + = 1.20 * x1 + 1.50 * x2 + 0.90 * x3 + 1.30 * x4 + 1.45 * x5 + 1.20 * x6 + 1.00 * x7, "AlliageCost"

# Quantity constraint in KGS.
prob + = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 == 5000, "RequestedQuantity"

# MIN constraints of% carbon, by alloy  // ITS NOT WHAT I NEED
prob + = x1> = 2.5, "MinCarboneRequirement1"
prob + = x2> = 3, "MinCarboneRequirement2"
prob + = x3> = 0, "MinCarboneRequirement3"
prob + = x4> = 0, "MinCarboneRequirement4"
prob + = x5> = 0, "MinCarboneRequirement5"
prob + = x6> = 0, "MinCarboneRequirement6"
prob + = x7> = 0, "MinCarboneRequirement7"

# MIN constraints of% copper, by alloy // ITS WRONG ITS NOT WHAT I NEED
prob + = x1> = 0, "MinCuivreRequirement1"
prob + = x2> = 0, "MinCuivreRequirement2"
prob + = x3> = 0.3, "MinCuivreRequirement3"
prob + = x4> = 90, "MinCuivreRequirement4"
prob + = x5> = 96, "MinCuivreRequirement5"
prob + = x6> = 0.4, "MinCuivreRequirement6"
prob + = x7> = 0.6, "MinCuivreRequirement7"

# MIN constraints of% of Manganese, by alloy // ITS WRONG ITS NOT WHAT I NEED
prob + = x1> = 1.3, "MinManganeseRequirement1"
prob + = x2> = 0.8, "MinManganeseRequirement2"
prob + = x3> = 0, "MinManganeseRequirement3"
prob + = x4> = 0, "MinManganeseRequirement4"
prob + = x5> = 4, "MinManganeseRequirement5"
prob + = x6> = 1.2, "MinManganeseRequirement6"
prob + = x7> = 0, "MinManganeseRequirement7"

# MAX constraints of% of Manganese, by alloy // ITS WRONG ITS NOT WHAT I NEED
prob + = x1 <= 1.3, "MaxManganeseRequirement1"
prob + = x2 <= 0.8, "MaxManganeseRequirement2"
prob + = x3 <= 0, "MaxManganeseRequirement3"
prob + = x4 <= 0, "MaxManganeseRequirement4"
prob + = x5 <= 4, "MaxManganeseRequirement5"
prob + = x6 <= 1.2, "MaxManganeseRequirement6"
prob + = x7 <= 0, "MaxManganeseRequirement7"


# 5. MAX constraints from available stock, by alloy // I THINK IT IS OK
prob + = x1 <= 4000, "MaxStock"
prob + = x2 <= 3000, "MaxStock1"
prob + = x3 <= 6000, "MaxStock2"
prob + = x4 <= 5000, "MaxStock3"
prob + = x5 <= 2000, "MaxStock4"
prob + = x6 <= 3000, "MaxStock5"
prob + = x7 <= 2500, "MaxStock6"



# The problem data is written to an .lp file
prob.writeLP ( "WhiskasModel.lp")

# We use the solver
prob.solve ()

# The status of the solution
print ("Status:", LpStatus [prob.status])

# We magnify and display the optimums of each var
for v in prob.variables ():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# The result of the objective function is here
print ("Total", value (prob.objective))
```

This is the answer, but of course, it is wrong, cause I dont know how to do the constraints :

```
Status: Optimal
Aluminum_alloy_1 = 1.2
Aluminum_alloy_2 = 0.6
Copper_alloy_1 = 90.0
Alloy_of_copper_2 = 96.0
Alloy_of_fer_1 = 2.5
Alloy_of_fer_2 = 3.0
Iron_alloy_3 = 4806.7
Total 4,591.76,999,999,999,995
```

**EDIT** Hello ! 
This is the improved version 2 of my code, sorry, it is in french, but i bet you can see what i mean , it still doesn't work , thought... but closer to what I need  :

```
Mining and metals

In the manufacture of steel with permeable materials, sur wants to reduce the cost of producing this steel
to earn more money but still respecting the important characteristics of quality steel



    # Characteristics of the steel to be made



    """ Elément     % minimal   % Max   
    Carbone             2         3 
    Cuivre              0.4      0.6    
    Manganèse           1.2      1.65 

     """
    # Characteristics, stocks and purchase price of alloys at KILO
    """ 
    Alliage             C %     Cu %    Mn %    Stocks kg   Prix €/kg
    Alliage de fer 1    2,50    0,00    1,30    4000        1,20
    Alliage de fer 2    3,00    0,00    0,80    3000        1,50
    Alliage de fer 3    0,00    0,30    0,00    6000        0,90
    Alliage de cuivre 1 0,00    90,00   0,00    5000        1,30
    Alliage de cuivre 2 0,00    96,00   4,00    2000        1,45
    Alliage d'alu 1     0,00    0,40    1,20    3000        1,20
    Alliage d'alu 2     0,00    0,60    0,00    2500        1,00 
    """

    # Importer la lib PuLP 
    from pulp import *

    #Créer la variable du problème
    prob = LpProblem("MinimiserLpAlliage",LpMinimize)

    # The 7 vars have a zero limit, these decision variables are expressed in KILOS
    x1 = LpVariable("Alliage de fer 1",0)
    x2 = LpVariable("Alliage de fer 2",0)
    x3 = LpVariable("Alliage de fer 3",0)
    x4 = LpVariable("Alliage de cuivre 1",0)
    x5 = LpVariable("Alliage de cuivre 2",0)
    x6 = LpVariable("Alliage d'alu 1",0)
    x7 = LpVariable("Alliage d'alu 2",0)


    # The objective function is to minimize the total cost of the alloys in EUROS


    prob += 1.20 * x1 + 1.50 * x2 + 0.90 * x3 + 1.30 * x4 + 1.45 * x5 + 1.20 * x6 + 1.00 * x7, "CoutAlliages"

    # Quantity constraint in KGS.
    prob += x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 == 5000, "QuantitéDemandée"

    # Carbon stress.
    prob += (2.50 * x1  + 3.00 * x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 ) / 5000 <= 3,"carBmax"
    prob += (2.50 * x1  + 3.00 * x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 ) / 5000 >= 2,"carBmin"

    # Constraint cu  .
    prob += (x1 + x2 + 0.30 * x3 +  90 * x4  +  96 * x5 + 0.40 * x6 + 0.60 * x7) / 5000 <= 0.6,"cuBmax"
    prob += (x1 + x2 + 0.30 * x3 +  90 * x4  +  96 * x5 + 0.40 * x6 + 0.60 * x7) / 5000 >= 0.4,"cuBmin"

    # Constraint Manganèse.
    prob += (1.30 * x1 + 0.80 * x2 + x3 + x4  + 4 *  x5  + 1.20 * x6 + x7 ) / 5000 <= 1.65,"mgBmax"
    prob += (1.30 * x1 + 0.80 * x2 + x3 + x4  + 4 *  x5  + 1.20 * x6 + x7 ) / 5000 >= 1.2,"mgBmin"

    # 5. MAX constraints from available stock, by alloy
    prob += x1 <= 4000 , "MaxStock"
    prob += x2 <= 3000 , "MaxStock1"  
    prob += x3 <= 6000  , "MaxStock2"  
    prob += x4 <= 5000 , "MaxStock3"   
    prob += x5 <= 2000 , "MaxStock4" 
    prob += x6 <= 3000  , "MaxStock5"
    prob += x7 <= 2500  , "MaxStock6"


    # The problem data is written to an .lp file
    prob.writeLP("acier.lp")

    # On utilise le solveur
    prob.solve()

    # The status of the solution
    print ("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

    # We magnify and display the optimums of each var
    for v in prob.variables():
        print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

    # The result of the objective function is here
    print ("Total payable in euros", value(prob.objective))

    """ Status: Infeasible
    Alliage_d'alu_1 = 0.0
    Alliage_d'alu_2 = 0.0
    Alliage_de_cuivre_1 = 0.0
    Alliage_de_cuivre_2 = 0.0
    Alliage_de_fer_1 = 0.0
    Alliage_de_fer_2 = 0.0
    Alliage_de_fer_3 = 10000.0
    Total à payer en euros 9000.0 """
```

> ```
> The book says the result with the excel solver is :
>
> iron_1 : 4000 kgs 
> iron_2 : 0 kgs 
> iron_3 : 397.76kgs 
> cu_1   : 0 kgs 
> cu_2   : 27.61kgs 
> al_1   : 574.62kgs 
> al_2   : 0kgs
>
> Cost in euros 5887.57 
> Steel contains 2% carb, 0.6 % cu, 1.2 %
> ```

manganese

Excel tab :
[image: Excel pic]

Solver pic :
[image: solver pic]

Comment: Status: Optimal, not unbounded, anyway, I need someboy to help me setting my alloy constraints

Comment: This a professional book , this is not a problem of my own, the problem described works in the excel solver, . I need to produce 5000 kgs of steel, by choosing between 7 elements, and to reduce the cost . The result must respect the main steel caracteristics, for example, the carbon amount inside of my produced steel must be between 2% and 3 % . All of the necessary data is present, its just that there is a link between my two array , and the percents who needs to be done, that I dont know how to do because I have 90% of copper .

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem is how you are understanding/applying percentages. My recommendation would be to convert percentages [0-100] to fractional numbers [0-1.0] as early as possible.

In excel when a cell says `50%` the numeric value of the cell is actually `0.5`. Working with percentages in this way means you don't have to keep dividing out by 100, and can multiply one percentage with another and it all just works.

The code below does what you want:

```
"""
 Mining and metals

We make steel with raw materials, we want to reduce the cost of producing this steel
to make more money, but still respecting the minimum characteristics of quality steel

"""

# Minimize the cost of metal alloys.
# Characteristics of the steel to be made

"""Element      %Minimum  %Max   %Real (it is a var)
   Carbon       2         3      2.26
   Copper       0.4       0.6    0.60
   Manganese    1.2       1.65   1.20

"""

# Characteristics, stocks and purchase price of alloys
"""
Alloy          C%   Cu%   Mn%     Stocks kg Price € / kg
Iron alloy     2.50 0.00  1.30    4000      1.20
Iron alloy     3.00 0.00  0.80    3000      1.50
Iron alloy     0.00 0.30  0.00    6000      0.90
Copper alloy   0.00 90.00 0.00    5000      1.30
Copper alloy   0.00 96.00 4.00    2000      1.45
Aluminum alloy 0.00 0.40  1.20    3000      1.20
Aluminum alloy 0.00 0.60  0.00    2500      1.00
"""

# Import the PuLP lib
from pulp import *

# Create the problem variable
prob = LpProblem ("MinimiserLpAlliage", LpMinimize)

# Problem Data
input_mats = ["iron_1", "iron_2", "iron_3",
              "cu_1", "cu_2",
              "al_1", "al_2"]

input_costs = {"iron_1": 1.20, "iron_2": 1.50, "iron_3": 0.90,
               "cu_1":   1.30, "cu_2": 1.45,
               "al_1":   1.20, "al_2":   1.00}

#                               C%     Cu%   Mn%
input_composition = {"iron_1": [0.025, 0.000,  0.013],
                     "iron_2": [0.030, 0.000,  0.008],
                     "iron_3": [0.000, 0.003,  0.000],
                     "cu_1":   [0.000, 0.900,  0.000],
                     "cu_2":   [0.000, 0.960,  0.040],
                     "al_1":   [0.000, 0.004,  0.012],
                     "al_2":   [0.000, 0.006,  0.000]}

input_stock = {"iron_1": 4000, "iron_2": 3000, "iron_3": 6000,
               "cu_1": 5000, "cu_2":  2000,
               "al_1": 3000, "al_2": 2500}

request_quantity = 5000

Carbon_min = 0.02
Carbon_max = 0.03

Cu_min = 0.004
Cu_max = 0.006

Mn_min = 0.012
Mn_max = 0.0165

# Problem variables - amount in kg of each input
x = LpVariable.dicts("input_mat", input_mats, 0)

# The objective function is to minimize the total cost of the alloys in EUROS for a given quantity in KGS
prob += lpSum([input_costs[i]*x[i] for i in input_mats]), "AlliageCost"

# Quantity constraint in KGS.
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in input_mats]) == request_quantity, "RequestedQuantity"

# MIN/MAX constraint of carbon in resultant steel
prob += lpSum([x[i]*input_composition[i][0] for i in input_mats]) >= Carbon_min*request_quantity, "MinCarbon"
prob += lpSum([x[i]*input_composition[i][0] for i in input_mats]) <= Carbon_max*request_quantity, "MaxCarbon"

# MIN/MAX constraints of copper in resultant steel
prob += lpSum([x[i]*input_composition[i][1] for i in input_mats]) >= Cu_min*request_quantity, "MinCu"
prob += lpSum([x[i]*input_composition[i][1] for i in input_mats]) <= Cu_max*request_quantity, "MaxCu"

# MIN/MAX constraints of manganese in resultant steel
prob += lpSum([x[i]*input_composition[i][2] for i in input_mats]) >= Mn_min*request_quantity, "MinMn"
prob += lpSum([x[i]*input_composition[i][2] for i in input_mats]) <= Mn_max*request_quantity, "MaxMn"


# MAX constraints of available stock
for i in input_mats:
    prob += x[i] <= input_stock[i], ("MaxStock_" + i)

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# The status of the solution
print ("Status:", LpStatus [prob.status])

# Dislay the optimums of each var
for v in prob.variables ():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# Display mat'l compositions
Carbon_value = sum([x[i].varValue*input_composition[i][0] for i in input_mats])/request_quantity
Cu_value = sum([x[i].varValue*input_composition[i][1] for i in input_mats])/request_quantity
Mn_value = sum([x[i].varValue*input_composition[i][2] for i in input_mats])/request_quantity

print ("Carbon content: " + str(Carbon_value))
print ("Copper content: " + str(Cu_value))
print ("Manganese content: " + str(Mn_value))

# The result of the objective function is here
print ("Total", value (prob.objective))
```

From which I get:

```
Status: Optimal
input_mat_al_1 = 574.62426
input_mat_al_2 = 0.0
input_mat_cu_1 = 0.0
input_mat_cu_2 = 27.612723
input_mat_iron_1 = 4000.0
input_mat_iron_2 = 0.0
input_mat_iron_3 = 397.76302
Carbon content: 0.02
Copper content: 0.006000000036
Manganese content: 0.012000000008
Total 5887.57427835
```

Comment: Hello ! I can't express how much I am gratefull ! I will look really closely at your code and try it out  !

Comment: You are fantastic , thank you , I'm trying this out now .